# How to specify connection string when using db context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using the Repository pattern for EF and have ran into a problem in that I cannot figure out how to set the connection string for the `DbContext` through a variable.  Currently my constructor is parameterless (it has to be to fit with he pattern) i.e.

```
IUnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork<EMDataContext>();
DeviceService deviceService = new DeviceService(uow);
var what = deviceService.GetAllDevices();


public UnitOfWork()
{
    _ctx = new TContext();
    _repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    _disposed = false;
}
```

`EMDataContext` used to take a string in its constructor to define the `ConnectionString` but can no longer do that so how do I actually tell the `EMDataContext` what to connect to when its created in this fashion?

Comment: what happenes in `new UnitOfWork<EMDataContext>();` ?

Comment: Do you need to connect to more than one database? If not, use web.config or app.config files.

Comment: @JensKloster Updated. ta - Not at the moment, the question is how to pass in the connection string?

Comment: @Chris ok. What is known about `TContext` ? does it inherit something that allows you to set a connctionstring? Also - a .config file is a good place for the connectionstring. EF will look for it there if you don't directly specify where it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question can be rewritten as "How to pass an argument to a generic type constructor with a `new()` constraint".

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx):

> The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class
>   declaration must have a public parameterless constructor.

Since the bare Entity Framework context doesn't contain a parameter-less constructor, I assume your `EMDataContext` is your custom context that derives from it:

```
public class EMDataContext : DbContext
{
      // parameterless ctor, since you're using new() in UnitOfWork<TContext>
      public EMDataContext() : base(???)
      {
      }

      public EMDataContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
      {
      }
}
```

Now, I would argue that your `EMDataContext` is incapable of having a parameter-less constructor, hence incapable of the `new()` constraint as well, especially when you're saying that you **do** want to pass a connection-string parameter.

Try to change your `UnitOfWork` to accept an already-initialized context in it's constructor (common pattern):

```
public class UnitOfWork<TContext>
{
    public UnitOfWork(TContext ctx)
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
    }
}
```

Alternatively (if you still want to "fit the pattern"), try to instantiate the context using `Activator`:

```
public class UnitOfWork<TContext>
{
    public UnitOfWork(string connectionString)
    {
        _ctx = (TContext)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TContext), new[] { connectionString });
    }
}
```